Spring Jar Upgrade from 5.x to 6.x Version
I'm upgrading my project from Spring 5.x to Spring 6.1.13 due to vulnerabilities in the older version.
However, during the upgrade, I noticed that the CommonsMultipartResolver class from the org.springframework.web.multipart.commons package has been removed from the spring-web.jar.
I found that the StandardServletMultipartResolver class can be used as an alternative. However, I'm having trouble finding a replacement for the setMaxUploadSize(int) and setDefaultEncoding(String) methods, which were available in CommonsMultipartResolver class, in the newer Spring 6.x version.
What should I do to handle this?

There doesn't seem to be a replacement for those options.

According to Upgrading to Spring Framework 6.x as you've mentioned you have to use StandardServletMultipartResolver but there is no way to set custom parameters.
Without any piece of code I can't help you with an implementation but I could give you steps to follow.
What can you do ?
Just use default StandardServletMultipartResolver without any additional configuration in this case spring will handle all configuration stuff, because all Servlet 5.0+ containers have built-in multipart support.
If you have use-cases where default values should be changed like maxUploadSize of defaultEncoding
Use commons-fileupload for jakarta.servlet to have more details check this post commons-fileupload-and-jakarta-servlet and jetty-11-and-commons-fileupload.
Some other examples how you can handle it you will be able to find out reading comments related to this GitHub issue 29562
